# What does the "I" mean in the xcode navigation pane?

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4.3

I have what appears to be an "I" beside one of my files in the Xcode navigation frame. I assume that it has something to do with version control (I'm using svn). However I can't figure out what it means or how to get rid of it. I do all my svn interaction through Terminal, and an svn status returns nothing. I've committed and updated to no effect.

I'm using Xcode 4.3 with Lion.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means 'Ignored'

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why it was being ignored, but I added it through Terminal and it removed the I.